# ImageView width does not match parent

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

**What I have:** `ScrollView`, inside it 
`LinearLayout`

(`orientation="vertical", 
layout_width="match_parent", 
layout_height="wrap_content"`),

inside it

`ImageView`

(`layout_width="match_parent", 
layout_height="wrap_content"`)  and

`TextView`.

**What I want:** `ImageView` should keep aspect ratio and math parent width, and text below `ImageView`.

I used differnt combinations of `ImageView params`: *`adjustViewBounds true/false` and all `scaleType`*, but I can't get what I want:

1. If I use scaleType centerCrop - top and bottom part if image cropped.
2. If I use scaleType center - empty space in left and right
3. If I use scaleType fitXY - image does not keep aspect ratio

So I can not make the image more in height, how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you actually post your layout xml and maybe a screen showing what you get and what it should look like? It is way easier to read the code than to get it by a description...

Comment: What if the image is smaller than the parent?  Should it be scaled up?  This will distort the image.

Comment: Try `scaleType="fitCenter"` for your ImageView

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       >
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:background="#f0f"
        />  
<TextView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Always work!!"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:textSize="26sp"
           />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Note: if `scaleType` does not help,  try to use `android:background=""` instead  `android:src=""`

[image]